# SwiftUI isSearching dismiss behaviour on iOS 15

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a SwiftUI view with a search bar on iOS 15. When the search bar is activated, a search list is presented, when no search is active, a regular content view is shown.
The problem I am facing is that when I activate a navigation link from the search list, when the navigation starts to take effect, the `isSearching` flag is turned to `false` and the regular content view is shown, even though I would want to search to stay active, just like when we would have a list/table and the user would select a row: the search stays active, and when the user navigates back, the search results are still displayed.

Is there a way in SwiftUI to control how the `isSearching` is changed?

I put together a small sample project that demoes the problem:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentView.ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ContentViewWrapper(viewModel: viewModel)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Searchable")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .searchable(text: $viewModel.searchString, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always), prompt: "Search")
            .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: View model for the content view

extension ContentView {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var isShowingDestinationScreen = false
        @Published var isSearching = false
        @Published var searchString = ""
        
        func buttonTapped() {
            if !isShowingDestinationScreen {
                isShowingDestinationScreen = true
            }
        }
        
        func isSearchingHasChanged(newValue: Bool) {
            if isSearching != newValue {
                isSearching = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Wrapper for the content view so it can be used with the searchable API

struct ContentViewWrapper: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentView.ViewModel
    @Environment(\.isSearching) var isSearching
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if viewModel.isSearching {
                NavigationLink(
                    isActive: $viewModel.isShowingDestinationScreen,
                    destination: {
                        DestinationView()
                            .navigationTitle("Destination")
                    }, label: {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                )
                
                SearchList() {
                    viewModel.buttonTapped()
                }
            } else {
                ContentViewMenu()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: isSearching) { newValue in
            viewModel.isSearchingHasChanged(newValue: newValue)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Just three simple screens below

struct ContentViewMenu: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Content View Menu")
    }
}

struct SearchList: View {
    var destinationButtonTapped: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Search list")
            Button("Go to destination") {
                destinationButtonTapped()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DestinationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Destination")
    }
}
```

Also here is a short video showing the behaviour: note how when the `Go to destination` button is tapped, the screen is updated to the content view because `isSearching` turns false.

Is there a way to keep `isSearching` `true` in this case?

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two options here:

1. Normally, when users click on a search field, we expect them to always enter something. It is not possible that someone clicks on a search field without typing anything, otherwise it's just an accident touch, so anything should not execute because of this. Your solution here is: you don't have to do anything at all. Just type anything to the search bar after you clicked on it; you can even just input a space, then your search and search result will always remain active no matter what.
2. If you still want your search bar to be active even though there is zero interaction or input with the search bar, you can adjust some part of your ContentViewWrapper as below(But I think it's not practical to do this because why would you want your search bar to be active without any input?):

code:

```
struct ContentViewWrapper: View {

@ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentView.ViewModel
@Environment(\.isSearching) var isSearching
//new code
@State var isShowing = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        //new code
        if viewModel.isSearching || isShowing {
            NavigationLink(
                isActive: $viewModel.isShowingDestinationScreen,
                destination: {
                    DestinationView()
                        .navigationTitle("Destination")
                }, label: {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            )
            .onAppear {
                isShowing = true
            }
        }
        //new code
        if isShowing {
            SearchList() {
                viewModel.buttonTapped()
            }
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: isSearching) { newValue in
        viewModel.isSearchingHasChanged(newValue: newValue)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tail. I think you can probably find reasonable use cases where you might want the search bar to stay active even though no search text is entered, e.g. you might have search suggestions, or my use case where you just want to have a banner that's tappable. 

re the approach you provided, I think the problem is that the search bar goes back to "inactive" mode, e.g. the `Done` button would not be shown. Maybe there is a way to intercept the dismissal, and override the value, but I wasn't able to figure that out just yet - If that is even possible.